Install Xvfb as noon root user
Do you know how can I intall Xvfb as non root user? I need to execute some Cypress tests I used this command
conda install conda-forge::xvfbwrapper

to install Xvfb:
pip show xvfbwrapper
Name: xvfbwrapper
Version: 0.2.9
Summary: run headless display inside X virtual framebuffer (Xvfb)
Home-page: https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper
Author: Corey Goldberg
Author-email: cgoldberg _at_ gmail.com
License: MIT

But I'm still not able to execute Cypress tests in headless mode:
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 12.13.0
Your system is missing the dependency: Xvfb
Install Xvfb and run Cypress again.
Read our documentation on dependencies for more information:
https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.
----------
Error: spawn Xvfb ENOENT
----------
Platform: linux-x64 (Red Hat Linux - 7.9)
Cypress Version: 12.13.0

Do you know how can I install, Xvfb as non root user or what I'm missing?

You need to install the Xvfb program itself too. For example using the dnf command. If you don't have root access you can try your luck with either downloading the RPM yourself and unpacking it, or compiling Xvfb from source.
